# Pesquisar e adicionar os dados das tabelas no formulário [Nodejs e MongoDB]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express.js

Estou tentado carregar os dados de de 3 tabelas em um formulário da **routa**, mas ele pega apenas os dados do **Municipality** no select do **Country**. É suposto ter 3 selects (Country; Country; Municipality) e cada um trazer os seus dados.
**Como faço isso usando a lógica do código abaixo?**

```js
router.get('/unidade/add', function(req, res){
        Country,City,Municipality.find().then(function(countries, cities, municipalities){
            res.render("ferramentas/addunidade", {countries: countries, cities: cities, municipalities: municipalities})
        }).catch(function(err){
            req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao carregar o formulário")
            res.redirect("/ferramentas/unidade")
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode aguardar a finalização das promessas:

```
router.get('/unidade/add', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const [countries, cities, municipalities] = await Promise.all([Country.find(), City.find(), Municipality.find()]);
    res.render('ferramentas/addunidade', { countries, cities, municipalities });
  } catch(e) {
    req.flash('error_msg', 'Houve um erro ao carregar o formulário');
    res.redirect('/ferramentas/unidade');
  };
});
```

---

> [**Promise​.all()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
>
> O método `Promise.all(iterable)` retorna uma única `Promise` que resolve quando todas as `promises` no argumento iterável forem resolvidas ou quando o iterável passado como argumento não contém `promises`. É rejeitado com o motivo da primeira `promise` que foi rejeitada.

---

> [**Funções assíncronas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)
>
> A declaração **async function** define uma função assíncrona, que retorna um objeto [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).
>
> Você também pode definir funções assíncronas usando uma [expressão async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).
>
> Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Quando a função assíncrona retorna um valor, a `Promise` será resolvida com o valor retornado. Quando a função assíncrona lança uma exceção ou algum valor, a `Promise` será rejeitada com o valor lançado.
>
> Uma função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), que pausa a execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da `Promise` passada, e depois retoma a execução da função assíncrona e retorna o valor resolvido.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, funcionou como queria. Mas caso eu quisesse que aparecesse apenas os estados de um determinado pais e as províncias deste estado, como ficaria?

Comment: @HorácioPedrosa nesse caso que você descreveu a dúvida é outra. Para obter uma resposta dessa dúvida você deve abrir outra pergunta e alguém que tenha o conhecimento necessário para respondê-la irá te instruir